# Requests get very slow after downloading some files

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I have a Nodejs App running on background and I have a code in frontend to send xhr request to load the assets like videos , audios...

Everything is going fine until I reach 32mb transferred then the transfer gets really slow and for the next 10 mb to load I need more time than what I needed to reach 30MBs!!??

Sometimes and not all the times I get this error for loading a video too:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Here you can see the end of the fast part of the preloading where suddenly everything gets slow:

[image]

Any suggestions why this is happening and how to fix this is a good point to start and debug this and it's really appreciated ...

For me it seems something get's full after 30 MBs :)

Comment: So this is all on one PC ... no network bandwidth to deal with? Do you have network "throttling" enabled in your developer  tools?

Comment: No all devices behave the same... No throttling

Comment: what does "all devices behave the same" even mean in response to my question? Let me ask a different way - is the server and client on the same device - I ask, to rule out network issues

Comment: No, the app is online and I test this with my mobile and laptop and other devices.

Comment: right ... so what you have there is the bandwidth issue

Comment: What is  bandwidth issue ? Can I do something for it ?